# vba kill a file using a variable

Tags: vba, excel

I have written code which stores the original file which is opened, as the variable fileName and this is used to save a new version of the file with a slightly different name. I have written the code to kill the original file but its not behaving quite as it should.

I am getting file not found on the kill line.

```
 'Deletes the original copy
  Kill "S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment Limited\" & fileName & 
  ".txt"


   Sub BACSConversion()

   Dim MyNewBook As String
   Dim MySaveFile As String
   Dim fileToOpen As Variant
   Dim fileName As String
   Dim sheetName As String
   Dim rCopy As Range

  'Turn off display alerts
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  'Turn off screen updates
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   'Ensures that the file open directory is always the same
   ChDir "S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment Limited\"

  'Opens the folder to location to select txt file
   fileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
    If fileToOpen <> False Then
    Workbooks.OpenText fileName:=fileToOpen, _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
    End If
'Creates the file name based on txt file name
fileName = Mid(fileToOpen, InStrRev(fileToOpen, "\") + 1)
'Creates the sheet name based on the active txt file
sheetName = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 4)

  'Rename the original text file
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment 
   Limited\" 
   & "DNU_" & fileName & ".txt")

'Save active file as...
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment 
 Limited\BACS File Original\" & _
   fileName & ".CSV"), FileFormat:=xlCSV

 'Selects all data in column A and copies to clipboard
   Set rCopy = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))

 'Open the original document where the BACS file is located
  Workbooks.Open "S:\Accounts (New)\Management Information 
 (Analysis)\Phil 
  Hanmore - Analysis\bacs conversation calc.xlsx"
 'Selects the worksheet called "Original"
  Sheets("Original").Range("A:A").ClearContents

  'Paste selected values from previous sheet
    rCopy.Copy
   Sheets("Original").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

  'Selects appropriate worksheet - Non-MyPayFINAL
   Sheets("Non-MyPay FINAL").Select

  'Selects all data in column A and copies to clipboard
   Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Select
   Selection.Copy

'Add a new workbook
  Workbooks.Add
 'Paste selected values from previous sheet
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

 'Build SaveAs file name (for CSV file)
  MySaveFile = Format(Now(), "DDMMYYYY") & "NonMyPayFINAL" & ".CSV"
 'Save template file as...(for CSV file)
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment 
  Limited\" 
  & MySaveFile), FileFormat:=xlCSV

  'Build SaveAs file name (for Txt file)
  MySaveFile = Format(Now(), "DDMMYYYY") & "NonMyPayFINAL" & ".Txt"
 'Save template file as...(for Txt file)
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment 
  Limited\" 
  & MySaveFile), FileFormat:=xlTextWindows

  'Close the new saved file
   ActiveWorkbook.Close

  'Selects appropriate worksheet - MyPayFINAL
   Sheets("MyPay FINAL").Select

  'Selects all data in column A and copies to clipboard
   Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Select
   Selection.Copy

  'Add a new workbook
   Workbooks.Add
   'Paste selected values from previous sheet
   Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

   'Build SaveAs file name (for CSV file)
    MySaveFile = Format(Now(), "DDMMYYYY") & "MyPayFINAL" & ".CSV"
  'Save template file as...(for CSV file)
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment 
   Limited\" 
  & MySaveFile), FileFormat:=xlCSV

   'Build SaveAs file name (for Txt file)
   MySaveFile = Format(Now(), "DDMMYYYY") & "MyPayFINAL" & ".Txt"
   'Save template file as...(for Txt file)
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment 
    Limited\" 
   & MySaveFile), FileFormat:=xlTextWindows

  'Close the new saved file
   ActiveWorkbook.Close
  'Close original source workbook (template)
   Workbooks("bacs conversation calc").Close
  'Close final workbook
   ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True
  'Deletes the original copy
   Kill "S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment Limited\" & fileName & 
  ".txt"

  'Displays message box
  MsgBox "Your file has been processed successfully!", vbExclamation

  'Turn on display alerts
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 'Turn on screen updates
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  End Sub
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  I'd assume some for of file not found error?

Comment: @ainwood That is correct, file not found!

Comment: So that's what the issue is.  Something with the structure of the filename - does the filename already have the path attached to it?  try `smodifiedFile = "S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment Limited\" & fileName & 
  ".txt"` and then `Debug.Print sModifiedFile`

Comment: @ainwood I have updated the original post to include all of the code, where abouts would you suggest I put the additional lines?

Comment: @ainwood I have done as you suggested, I declared smodifiedFile as a string and when I run through I can see that smodifiedFile picks up the file name (in the immediate window) but if I just put Kill smodifiedFile then I get file not found. I am wondering how I delete the file based on the variable?!

Comment: The purpose of getting sModifiedFile as a variable is to help with debugging.  You can see the value in the immediate window - does it look like a valid file path?  Can you go through window explorer and find it?  However, there is an easier way.  Looking at your code, the original file that was opened is stored in the variable **fileToOpen**.  As far as I can see, you don't modify that variable, so you could just kill that directly.  `kill fileToOpen`.  But be careful - you can easily delete a file that you don't want to, if someone just browses to the wrong file and tried to open it!

Comment: @ainwood I was using the wrong variable when doing the killing, using fileToOpen has worked perfectly!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @ainwood, I have realized that the answer really was quite simple. Where I was using `filename` Variable this meant that the file could not be found - using `fileToOpen` solved the problem completely.